# What cards are in the Nook store DIY card packs?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Nook's Cranny is selling a few different packs: "DIY for Beginners", "Test Your DIY Skills", "Wildest Dreams DIY"

What cards are in each pack? If I already "learned" the DIY skill, will I still receive the card (to give to someone else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in DIY For Beginners you receive:

```
 Ocarina

 Wooden-block toy

 Old-fashioned washtub

 Stone stool

 Frying pan

 Hay bed
```

In Test Your DIY Skills:

```
 Mini DIY Workbench

 Wooden-block chair

 Wooden-block bookshelf

 Wooden-block stereo

 Rocking chair

 Swinging bench

 Ringtoss
```

And in Wildest Dreams DIY:

```
 Plain Sink

 Wooden Fish

 Brick Oven

 Iron Wall Lamp

 Ironwood Kitchenette

 Hearth
```

If you already have one or some of the recipes in the pack, you’ll still receive the other ones upon purchase. Since the Nephews send these recipes directly to your phone, you can’t get their cards to give to someone else.